# Why does adding convolution/pool layer crash Keras/Tensorflow model while running on RTX 3070/cudnn8/CUDA11.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

**System Info**

- OS: Windows 10,
- cudnn: 8.0,
- CUDA toolkit: 11.1 installed overtop of 10.2,
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 3070,
- CPU: Intel I7 10700f,
- Tensorflow: `tf.__version__==2.4.0rc-0` (have also tried with `tf-nightly-gpu` as late as Dec 7, 2020)
- CUDA, cudnn compiled manually from source

**Test Code**

The below code successfully compiles a model but crashes when `model.fit(...)` is called.

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

By removing the **convolutional** and **maxpooling** layers and just flattening the tensors after input the model is able to train fine (obviously the output of this model is useless but it is still able to train).

The error code when program crashes is >Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Additionally tensorflow is able to open library, find the GPU, and logs GPU as available when `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` is called

**UPDATE**
I opened an issue on the tensorflow github page which you can find  [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45611)

Comment: This is probably a bug, you are aware that rc means release candidate, and that nightly builds are unstable? Instead of asking a question here, you should report a bug to TensorFlow (in github) so it is fixed before the final 2.5 version is released. Also did you try version 2.4? (A non-rc one)

Comment: rc=release candidate; yes, nightly=unstable; yes. The issue is that the most recent stable release (2.3.1) does not support the ampere architecture (present on the 3000 series GPUs), I will report the issue on github, I just figured i'd ask here as well because i've seen people successfully run CNNs on 3000 series GPUs however most are using a linux distro

Comment: Unfortunately Linux is the first class citizen in most Deep Learning frameworks, with Windows being left over as second class, maybe it is a Windows specific bug, I would also try the latest versions (even rc).

Comment: thanks @Dr.Snoopy i'll give it a shot and see if any new info pops up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason when run in the IDE terminal an error message was being suppressed and `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` was logged as the error message.

When run from the command line the below error messages were displayed instead of logging the exit code error.

```
Could not load library cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126
Please make sure cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!
```

I recognized this was a package included in the cudnn library and copy and pasted it from the bin folder in cudnn to NVIDIA GPU computing toolkit > CUDA > V11.0 > bin. This process was repeated for the below packages and the issue was resolved.

```
cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
```

Comment: I already have those files pasted on `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\bin` but still get the same error

Comment: is that folder added to your envrionment variables?